# How to train an email server's junk filter using an IMAP offline client?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, spam-prevention

I frequently use offline email clients such as thunderbird and K-9. I also am trying to do a better job of training my email account's mail filter to more accurately filter junk email.

I see [thunderbird documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-junk-spam-messages) on it's junk training, but it seems that thunderbird's filter only applies to that client and not to the mail server,
so the training done in the client would not be relevant to webmail or to other IMAP clients accessing the account. There must be some way of marking messages as junk offline, such that imap can inform the server of those markings and operate to train the server's filter.

Is there some way of doing that? Is that what thunderbird (and K-9) already do, and I'm just misunderstanding in my assumption that thunderbird's filtering is done only within that particular client?

Answer (score 1):

There are **separate** rules on the IMAP server and on the local email client. Here is a specific example.

- GMail has its own set of rules to determine spam. You can report spam, in a web browser tab with GMail and help GMail to learn to block such mail; you can create a filter in a web browser tab with GMail and send all mail with those characteristics to *Spam*. These rules reside on the IMAP server. When a client connects, the messages have already been moved to the *Spam* folder.

[image: GMail Mark as Spam]

*Thunderbird* has *its* own set of rules to determine spam, which it calls *Junk*. You can mark a received message as *Junk*, in the *Thunderbird* client (not in a browser) and help *Thunderbird* to learn to move such mail to *Junk*; you can create a filter in *Thunderbird* to move all mail with those characteristics to the GMail *Spam* folder **after the message arrives**. These rules reside on the *Thunderbird* client.

[image: Thunderbird Marks as Junk]

It is *possible* that GMail could have implemented some way to recognize that messages with certain characteristics are frequently moved from *Inbox* to *Spam* when *Thunderbird* has done so; however I doubt this has been implemented (Google would *much* prefer you use their web client!).

Therefore, any "training" done through a particular *Thunderbird* client [**stays on that client**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1292889). It is not passed on to GMail, nor can it automatically be synced to another Thunderbird client.

Comment: True, it won't copy or sync automatically.  However, you can manual copy the training.dat file and it should work just fine.

Comment: @wsmwk implies, one can copy an entire *profile*, too, from one PC to another. Minor *caveat*: with an older version of T'Bird, transferring one or two files in a profile between Linux and Windows PC's was problematic, likely due to EOL convention difference.

Comment: I'm not intending to imply an entire profile can be copied - there can be nuances in doing so.

As for Linux vs Windows, yes, LF can be an issue.